# Beamer figure scaling problem

Tags: beamer, floats

I am trying to prepare a presentation with beamer however I keep getting an odd error while manipulating an image.

I am using `graphicx` package and the code is as follows:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\includegraphics{figure.png}
\end{frame}
```

This doesn't cause any problem but the figure is always out of the scale, so when I try to scale it as `\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figure.png}` (or any other manipulation) it returns this error:

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
>    
>                      \relax 
>   l.61    \end{frame}

I tried putting the figure in boxes, columns or prescale it so far nothing works. I cannot find the problem. Please help.

Update:
Here is the whole tex file so far:

`\documentclass[turkish]{beamer}`
`\usetheme{Berkeley}`
`\usecolortheme{seahorse}`
`\usefonttheme{serif}`

`` `\usepackage{xcolor}`
`\usepackage[turkish]{babel}`
`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
`\usepackage{graphicx}` ``

`%%%%%%%%KAPAK SAYFASI%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%`
`\title[] % (optional, only for long titles)`
`{title}`
`\author[author1, author2]`
`{author1\inst{1} \and author2\inst{1}}`
`\institute[University]`
`{\inst{1}%`
`Department\\`
`University}`
`\subject{subject}`
`\date[2015]`

`` `%%%%%%%%İÇİNDEKİLER ÖZELLİKLERİ%%%%%%%%%%%`
`\AtBeginSection[]`
`{`
`  \begin{frame}`
`    \frametitle{Table of Contents}`
`    \tableofcontents`
`  \end{frame}`
`}`
`\AtBeginSubsection[]`
`{`
`  \begin{frame}`
`    \frametitle{Table of Contents}`
`    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]`
`  \end{frame}`
`}` ``

`%%%%%%%%%%%%%SAYFALAR%%%%%%%%%%%%%%`


`\begin{document}`

`` `   \frame{\titlepage}`
`   `
`   \begin{frame}`
`       \frametitle{İçindekiler}`
`       \tableofcontents[currentsection]`
`   \end{frame}` ``

`\section{analysis}`
`\begin{frame}`
`\frametitle{}`
`\end{frame}`

`` `   \begin{frame}`
`       \frametitle{types}`
`%      \begin{center}`
`%          \includegraphics{16.png}`

`%      \end{center}`
`\tiny{\underline{source:} http://...}`
`   \end{frame}` ``

`\end{document}`

Comment: Add to your question a *complete*, little document allowing us to reproduce the problem mentioned.

Comment: are you using a babel language that makes `=` active?

Comment: Thank you, I removed babel, problem solved. But I need to use babel too, how can I override `= active`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `turkish` module for `babel` makes `=` active; use `\shorthandoff{=}` (since `inputenc` with `utf8` encoding is used, suppressing the shorthand is not a problem):

```
\documentclass[turkish]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{example-image-a}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been struggling with this for a while now. Everything works now.